# Watermark on hotlinked images?

Tags: jquery, watermark, hotlinking

I wonder if its possible to have a watermark on hotlinked images on an external site, but not on the original site? I'm using jQuery, can I do something about this?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: This is not possible on the client side; can you provide some information about your server environment?

Comment: @Nate: Why isn't it? I mean.. you can overlay watermarks at the very least.

Comment: @Mark, unless I misunderstood the question, the OP simply wants to watermark images that are hot-linked from other sites. This is simply not possible through client-side means, since we are not in control of that client, being a third-party website.

Comment: @Nate: Oh...nevermind. I thought he owned the external site too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible through a client-side technology. You will need to go server based.

If you have access to a server side technology, such as ASP.NET; you could expose all of your images through an ashx handler. This would let you display a water mark on some images, or not display images at all depending on the source.

Here's a great article on writing ashx handlers for images -- <s>[http://dotnetperls.com/ashx-handler/](http://dotnetperls.com/ashx-handler)</s> https://web.archive.org/web/20160311222240/http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx-handler

If you are using a *nix based server, @Jojo has some links for using php to similar effect.

After writing such a handler in ASP.NET or php, you'll need to check the HTTP Referer to see if it is a page on your site, or a third party site and then do the necessary image processing to produce your watermakr effect.

Comment: Link has gone 404.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to check that the referrer HTTP header matches your site's domain prior to running the watermarking code to determine whether a watermark is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with JQuery, since it is not at all involved when the image is served via hotlink. You'll need to do it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something on the back-end to add a watermark to hot-linked images.

Check out [this article](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/watermark-images-php) if you have access to PHP.